# Cannot wait for the result of MKDirections.calculate, getting nil instead of it

Tags: swift, mapkit, xcode8, mkdirection

I would like to calculate the real walking distance between my current location and a list of `CLLocation`s using `MKDirections.calculate`. However, for some reason the return command at the end of the function does not wait for the result and tries to return the empty variable. My code looks like this:

```
func getDistance (location1: CLLocation, location2: CLLocation) {
    let coordinates1 = location1.coordinate
    let placemark1 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates1)
    let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark1)
    let coordinates2 = location2.coordinate
    let placemark2 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates2)
    let destinationItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark2)

    let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = sourceItem
    request.destination = destinationItem
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
    request.transportType = .walking

    var distance: Double?

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculate { (response, error) in

        if var routeResponse = response?.routes {
            routeResponse.sort(by: {$0.expectedTravelTime < $1.expectedTravelTime})
            let quickestRoute: MKRoute = routeResponse[0]
            distance = Double(quickestRoute.distance)
        }
    }

    return distance //returns nil
}
```

And after that I would like to use the function in a code like this:

```
let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 47.0, longitude: 17.0)
let destinationArray = [CLLocation(latitude: 47.1, longitude: 17.1), CLLocation(latitude: 47.2, longitude: 17.2), CLLocation(latitude: 47.3, longitude: 17.3)]
var distanceArray: [Double] = []
for destination in destinationArray {
    distanceArray.append(getDistance(location1: myLocation, location2: destination))
}
return distanceArray
```

I have tried closures, but they did not work because I could not find a way to return distanceArray (the same error, it did not wait for the closure to run and returned the empty array). I have also tried DispatchGroups but they had no effect (maybe I implemented them in the wrong way).

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using MapKit & Swift 5

**Calculate distance between two location location, It will help anyone**

Sample Function : I have tested in Google Map as well as Apple Map

```
        let startLocation : CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 23.0952779, longitude: 72.5274129)
        let endLocation : CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 23.0981711, longitude: 72.5294229)
        let distance = startLocation.distance(from: endLocation)
        self.getDistance(departureDate: Date().adjust(hour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, day: 0, month: 0), arrivalDate: Date().adjust(hour: 8, minute: 10, second: 0, day: 0, month: 0), startLocation: startLocation, endLocation: endLocation) { (distanceInMeters) in

            print("fake distance: \(distance)")
            let fakedistanceInMeter = Measurement(value: distance, unit: UnitLength.meters)
            let fakedistanceInKM = fakedistanceInMeter.converted(to: UnitLength.kilometers).value
            let fakedistanceInMiles = fakedistanceInMeter.converted(to: UnitLength.miles).value
            print("fakedistanceInKM :\(fakedistanceInKM)")
            print("fakedistanceInMiles :\(fakedistanceInMiles)")


            print("actualDistance : \(distanceInMeters)")

            let distanceInMeter = Measurement(value: distanceInMeters, unit: UnitLength.meters)
            let distanceInKM = distanceInMeter.converted(to: UnitLength.kilometers).value
            let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeter.converted(to: UnitLength.miles).value
            print("distanceInKM :\(distanceInKM)")
            print("distanceInMiles :\(distanceInMiles)")
        }
```

Use of functions

```
                    self.getDistance(departureDate: trip.departure.dateTime, arrivalDate: trip.arrival.dateTime, startLocation: startLocation, endLocation: endLocation) { (actualDistance) in
                        print("actualDistance : \(actualDistance)")
                    }
```

**I am improved above function and added code here, I hope it will help someone.**

```
func calculateDistancefrom(departureDate: Date, arrivalDate: Date, sourceLocation: MKMapItem, destinationLocation: MKMapItem, doneSearching: @escaping (_ distance: CLLocationDistance) -> Void) {

        let request: MKDirections.Request = MKDirections.Request()

        request.departureDate = departureDate
        request.arrivalDate = arrivalDate

        request.source = sourceLocation
        request.destination = destinationLocation

        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
        request.transportType = .automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
        directions.calculate { (directions, error) in
            if var routeResponse = directions?.routes {
                routeResponse.sort(by: {$0.expectedTravelTime <
                    $1.expectedTravelTime})
                let quickestRouteForSegment: MKRoute = routeResponse[0]

                doneSearching(quickestRouteForSegment.distance)
            }
        }
    }

    func getDistance(departureDate: Date, arrivalDate: Date, startLocation : CLLocation, endLocation : CLLocation, completionHandler: @escaping (_ distance: CLLocationDistance) -> Void) {

        let destinationItem =  MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: startLocation.coordinate))
        let sourceItem      =  MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: endLocation.coordinate))
        self.calculateDistancefrom(departureDate: departureDate, arrivalDate: arrivalDate, sourceLocation: sourceItem, destinationLocation: destinationItem, doneSearching: { distance in
            completionHandler(distance)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it soon.

Comment: Please accept answer & upvote it. @ViktorCsimma. Best of luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

`directions.calculate` is an asynchronous function, so you need to wait for the function to return before returning the calculated distance. You should do this using a completion handler…

```
func getDistance(location1: CLLocation, location2: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {

    // etc 
    directions.calculate { (response, error) in

        if var routeResponse = response?.routes {
            routeResponse.sort(by: {$0.expectedTravelTime < $1.expectedTravelTime})
            let quickestRoute: MKRoute = routeResponse[0]

            completion(Double(quickestRoute.distance))
        }
    }
}
```

and then you should do something similar with your distance array. You'll need to wait for all `getDistance` calls to return, so you can use a `DispatchGroup` for that…

```
func getDistanceArray(completion: @escaping ([Double]) -> Void) {

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var distanceArray: [Double] = []

    for destination in destinationArray {
        group.enter()
        getDistance(location1: myLocation, location2: destination) { distance in
            distanceArray.append(distance)
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    group.wait()
    completion(distanceArray)
}
```

which you can call…

```
getDistanceArray { distanceArray in
    print(distanceArray)
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, can I ask for help about how to return the final distanceArray after this? I experience the same problem there, it only returns the empty array. Thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following closure:

```
func getDistance (location1: CLLocation, location2: CLLocation,
    completion: @escaping(Double?) -> Void) {

    let coordinates1 = location1.coordinate
    let placemark1 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates1)
    let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark1)
    let coordinates2 = location2.coordinate
    let placemark2 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates2)
    let destinationItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark2)

    let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = sourceItem
    request.destination = destinationItem
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
    request.transportType = .walking

    var distance: Double?

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculate { (response, error) in

        if var routeResponse = response?.routes {
            routeResponse.sort(by: {$0.expectedTravelTime < $1.expectedTravelTime})
            let quickestRoute: MKRoute = routeResponse[0]
            distance = Double(quickestRoute.distance)
            completion(distance)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 47.0, longitude: 17.0)
    let destinationArray = [CLLocation(latitude: 47.1, longitude: 17.1), CLLocation(latitude: 47.2, longitude: 17.2), CLLocation(latitude: 47.3, longitude: 17.3)]
    var distanceArray: [Double] = []
    for destination in destinationArray {
        getDistance(location1: myLocation, location2: destination) { distance in
            print("distance", distance)
            if let distance = distance {
                distanceArray.append(distance)
            }
        }
    }
    return distanceArray
```

Comment: Unfortunately, a similar problem occurs: it only returns [ ]. Could you please help me?